List of all posets of size $n$ for small $n$?
Is there a good reference for, or an easy way of generating, all Hasse diagrams of partially ordered sets of small size (say $n\leq 6$)? I am familiar with the OEIS entry A000112 listing the number of such posets of size $n$, but I am looking for a visual aid.

In sagemath, I think for p in Posets(6)[:5]: p.show() shows you the first five posets of order $6$ (and it can do more than $5$, but be careful not to accidentally show all 318 of them!). You can of course do more with them than just p.show() - you have p.hasse_diagram() and so on... see the sagemath documentation. I don't really know much about sage or the theory behind this but if you dig into the implementation a bit possibly you'll find a technique/reference/database.

https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/posets.pdf might interest you.

$n\le4$ diagrams at https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/notes-9-13--posets/

Labeled or unlabeled? In other words do you want to consider two distinct but automorphic posets as the same or not?

I'm fine with the post being closed, but the other linked "duplicate" post didn't emphasize the visual aspect I was looking for. In any case, @IzaakvanDongen's comment gives me what I need.
